# Regex to redirect all traffic to new path except ending with specified string

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I am trying to redirect all traffic from `wwww.mydomain.com/site/` to `wwww.mydomain.com` except for the URLs which contain `/events/` at the end. I am using the following regex right now which caters to most of the cases:
Source: `^/cra/(?!events)(.*)`
Target: `/$1`
It would redirect all traffic except the ones that contains `events` as string in URL, but the problem with this regex is, it's not redirecting `wwww.mydomain.com/site/events/myevent` to `wwww.mydomain.com/events/myevent`
I couldn't find something that would address mentioned use-case as well, would be great if anyone could help me out.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to redirect everything from

```
/site/*
```

to

```
/
```

BUT: if it contains

```
/events/
```

at the very end: do not redirect at all

If that is what you are trying to do, this should work.

```
^(?!.*(events\/\Z))(\/site\/)(.*)
```

Access to part to keep after the Redirection with $3.

Tip: [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a really neat site to figure out and play with regex.

Note that this only works if the "event/" part has a trailing '/'. But you can work from there I suppose.

**Edit:** Adjusted for Zohaib's comment

Comment: This really helps but one thing is missing here, I also want to keep remaining URL if there is other than /events/ i-e 
Source: wwww.mydomain.com/site/some-slug 
Target: wwww.mydomain.com/some-slug

Comment: To achieve that, make the last part after "/site/" a group. and pick thatgroup (should be $3). Also the group can be simplyfied to "(.*), resulting in this regex overall: ^(?!.*(events\/\Z))(\/site\/)(.*)